# Initialization using or operator

Tags: python

What is the correct way to initialize using or operator?
This is what I am attempting to do:

```
a = 7
b = 4

c = a or b

if (c > 5):
    print(c)
```

but it seems to only pick the value of a.
This is how I was attempting to apply the above:

```
ref = overall.dbs.reference('mycharacter')

first = ref.order_by_child('name')
first.start_at(sub_category)
first.end_at( sub_category + "\uf8ff").get()

second = ref.order_by_child('name')
second.start_at(sub_category.capitalize())
second.end_at(sub_category.capitalize() + "\uf8ff").get()

snapshot = first or second
```

Here I am attempting to perform an operation on snapshot which could return null
if the first letter of sub_category which is a variable provided either capitalized or not...trying to work around Firebase's orderby() case sensitivity.

Comment: What is the condition here! Please explain when you want `c`s value to be `a` and when you want it to be `b`?

Comment: What you want to achive>

Comment: It's unclear what the code is supposed to do. For the evaluation of boolean expressions, see explanations [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize a variable using the `or` operator like this `c = a or b`, Python will evaluate the parts of the right side of the expression, looking for "truthy" or "falsy" values. First, it evaluates `a`. If `a` is a truthy value, then `c` will receive the value of `a`, and Python won't evaluate the value of `b`. If `a` is a falsy value, then `c` will receive the value of `b` (the last part of the expression).

A falsy value in Python depends on the context. For collections, whatever is empty is considered a falsy value (`[]`, `()`, `{}`). For numbers, zero of any numeric type is considered falsy. `None` and `False` are also considered falsy values.

Truthy values are everything that is not falsy :). So, to keep it short, if you have something like this:

```py
a = b or c or d or e or f
```

Python will evaluate every part of the right side of the expression (from left to right) until it finds a truthy value to return, OR the last part of the expression, in case all of the previous parts of the expression are evaluated to `false`, as the example below.

```py
>>> a = 0
>>> b = []
>>> c = False
>>> d = a or b or c
>>> print(d)

Output:
False
```

Since all parts of the right side of the expression are falsy values, `d` will receive the value in the last part of the expression.